# Changing the photo on Japanese residence card (zairyu)

Tags: residence-cards, japan

I'm moving to Japan next month. I just learned that the photo I sent as part of the visa application will also be printed on my residence card.

Is there any procedure for changing this photo, in case I want a better one for the card? I'm guessing I cannot change it before moving to Japan, but will I be able to change it at the ward office later, or anywhere else?

Comment: You cannot change it in ward office. You need to change whole card and so you need to go to immigration office.

Comment: @Rambalac - Thanks. Can you please explain the procedure? Would they let me change it I ask or do I need a reason? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Did they use the visa photo? My recollection is that they take a new photo at immigration right after you land. This was a few years ago now though.

Comment: What does "better" mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can change just your picture, but according to this [link](http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/english/tetuduki/zairyukanri/kokansaikohu.html), you can change your non-expired residence card anytime you wish, even if it is not lost or damaged. You will have to pay a 1,300 yen fee.

The whole process is documented in the following [link](http://www.moj.go.jp/nyuukokukanri/kouhou/nyuukokukanri10_00013.html). Assuming that you are not changing your name on the card as well, you will need the following documents:

- Application form ([link](http://www.moj.go.jp/content/001291576.pdf)).
- A new picture with your name written on the back.
- Your current passport.
- Your current residence card.

You need to bring all the above papers to the immigration office in-charged of the area where you reside.